# C++ macro for repeated using std::xyz statements

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Sometimes my files look this way:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::size_type;
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid writing the common part every time? Something like this:

```
USING(std, cout, endl, string, vector, size_type);
```

I was thinking about a var-arg macro, but don't know if it's possible to iterate over those var args..

Comment: There is no way to iterate var-arg in macro.

Comment: I'm guessing Boost PP will let you do this, but it's usually better to just prefix things anyway, and to have readable code for the using declarations, which means an editor macro is probably a better choice than a coded one.

Comment: Would be nice if "using" supported comma delimited identifiers. Someone should propose this

Comment: @user1233963 This is such an obvious suggestion that I believe there must be a reason why it is not already in the language. But I agree, it would be cool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `namespace` for you code, where you need `std::cout`, `std::endl`, `std::`...

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace my {
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
}

int main() {
  using namespace my;
  cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley there is not a way to do what you want with the macro :(
At best you probably could "reduce" your work very slightly with:

```
USESTD(a) using std::a;
```

But... not sure its worth it, and Chirs's point is quite a good one from my point of view :) - I like to see where things come from too!